# Proper ARIA handling of breadcrumb navigation

Tags: html, accessibility, breadcrumbs, wai-aria

What can be done to improve the accessibility of a breadcrumb menu similar to:

```
<ul class="breadcrumbs" aria-label="breadcrumb navigation" role="navigation">
    <li><a href="~/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="~/news">News</a></li>
    <li class="unavailable"><a href="#">@Model.Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

Given in this example Home is the site root, News is the first child, and the unavailable class is the current item the /news/article item.

Is there anything that could be done to improve this such as using `rel` attributes or `aria-level` attributes?

Comment: What are `level` attributes?

Comment: @VolkerE. see Craig's answer below and the usage of `aria-level`

Comment: Alright, so its the `aria-level` attributes http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties and the HTML `rel` attributes http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes

Comment: I'm wondering if an unordered list is semantically best?! If you're following a tree-like structure. There is an order in the breadcrumb. Another point, it might help to add something for screen readers like 'You are here:' before the tree list.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would avoid the use of `aria-level` and use a `<ol>` element instead. It is best to avoid using aria attributes wherever a native alternative exists. Using aria adds an extra layer of complexity. Simple HTML is far better and already has semantics that are surfaced to AT. This is the [first rule of ARIA](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#rule1).

Borrowing from the [WAI-ARIA-Practices document](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#breadcrumb), breadcrumbs would look like something like this:

```
<nav aria-label="Breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
    <ol>
      <li>
        <a href="../../">
          WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../../#aria_ex">
          Design Patterns
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="../../#breadcrumb">
          Breadcrumb Pattern
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="./index.html" aria-current="page">
          Breadcrumb Example
        </a>
      </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Some notes:

1. Wrapping the breadcrumbs in a `<nav>` element lets screen reader users quickly find and jump to the breadcrumbs.
2. Using `<ol>` element surfaces an order to screen reader users.
3. The `<ol>` should be a child of the `<nav>`. Some implementations apply `role="nav"` to the `<ol>` itself. This is wrong and will override the default `<ol>` semantics.
4. `aria-current` informs screen reader users that this is the current page. If the last breadcrumb for the current page is not a link, the `aria-current` attribute is optional.

Comment: Can't argue with this being the absolute official answer as of CURRENT_YEAR.

Comment: This is the best solution to this question. One thing to not forget though is how to style the separators and make sure they are not announced by screen reader users. You can see the [full example of the breadcrumbs pattern](https://www.aditus.io/patterns/breadcrumbs/).

Answer (score 9):

Going from using a screen reader and reading [this blog post](http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/accessible-breadcrumbs-using-aria/), the `rel` attributes won't make a difference to A.T. As for using `aria-level`, it works if you put it on the anchor tags. I'd also advise wrapping the list in a `nav` element, for semantic purposes and to save the need of putting a navigation role on the list when you don't need to.

I wound up with this markup for what I think is a not-too-bad breadcrumb. Hide the bullets using CSS (I didn't stop to do that I'm afraid) and I'd say its good.

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" aria-level="1">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-level="2">News</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Craig. I hadn't thought about wrapping the `ul` in a `nav`. I had thought level was relevant but wasn't sure where it went exactly. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14180785/html5-nav-element-vs-role-navigation this seems to suggest always using `<nav role="navigation"`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out. Ok, that was quite an interesting read. I'll amend my answer to do that, as it would cover all bases. Not sure if its overkill or not, but it makes no difference, at least to NVDA in Firefox.

Comment: Do you have any ideas what should be done for the last link that's the current page? Should it be hidden from readers? Should it have an aria-level at all?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if there's any concrete answer to this. By convention, I guess most users of A.T would be used to it not being a link at all and just being plaintext. Or, another answer would be to put aria-disabled="true" on the anchor so they know its not clickable. I think either would be explanatory enough.

Comment: W3C Validator says that the elements with `aria-level` are missing a `role` attribute.

Comment: What role would you suggest for these links? I'd question whether its needed or not.

Comment: just to add to the topic: http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-level the `aria-level` attribute can be used on a item with role `listitem` - its place is on the `li`, not the `a` tag

Comment: After editing the question according to my comment, I've rolled back to the previous version based on the fact that the answer is based on the statement "As for using aria-level, it works if you put it on the anchor tags"

Answer (score 4):

When searching the Web for a thorough solution on accessible breadcrumbs, @Craig Brett's solution seemed good at first sight. But after reading several sources, `aria-level` seems to be misused there (besides a W3C Validation problem, see my comment above).
Therefor I like to propose this approach:

```
<nav aria-labelledby="bc-title" role="navigation">
    <h6 id="bc-title" class="vis-off">You are here:</h6>
    <a href="~/" aria-labelledby="bc-level-1">
        <span id="bc-level-1" class="vis-off">Homepage Website-Title </span>Home
    </a>
    <a href="~/news" aria-labelledby="bc-level-2">
        <span id="bc-level-2" class="vis-off">Level 2: News </span>News
    </a>
    <a href="#" aria-disabled="true">@Model.Title</a>
</nav>
```

In this solution we have an HTML5 sectioning element (`nav`), which **should** have a heading, and *tada* there it is. Class `vis-off` signifies an element that is just available to screen readers. With `aria-labelledby` I'm telling the screen reader to read that headline.

In contrast to Chris' solution, either the `<ul>` or `aria-level` is gone.
I'd so or so go for an `<ol>` if necessary, because the items are in *order*. Better leaving it out, otherwise it gets very verbose in many screen readers on every page ("List item 1…"). 
[`aria-level`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-level) seems to be misused in the solution above in my understanding. It **must** be [child of a role attribute like f.e. `role="list"`](http://www.maxability.co.in/wai-aria-overview/listitem-role/) and that role just signifies not structurally marked-up *non-interactive* lists.
Maybe a role `treeitem` might be more appropriate. IMHO it's overkill.

PS: I'm not using [BEM notation](https://bem.info/) here to shorten the ids and classes for readability.

Comment: Dear anonymous down-voter. Please give me some feedback! I've tested that solution in ChromeVox extension for Chrome http://www.chromevox.com/

And that worked fine for me!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I came across another source that said to use `aria-label="You are here:"` instead of `aria-labelledby` ([here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/menus/multiple-ways/)). Does your approach have an advantage over this?

Comment: @Jordan In my proposed solution I'm also taking care of HTML5 outlines http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#headings-and-sections -- which says every `section`, in this case `<nav>` should start with an explicit heading element. Although there currently is no implementation of outline algorithm by any browser vendor! So it's up to you what way to choose, I've followed the current standards' normative.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: I find the headings too verbose for something that isn't actually a heading on a page when I come across them on the web. But that's an opinion thing.

I'm not keen on having to explicitly put labels in when it's not needed and letting the AT use its own implementation when possible, as there is variation. Are you saying the only way to do this is to hide described by labels and put them on the links?

Comment: @Volker E: I had to implement a breadcrumb today hense why I came back to this question. I thought I'd try your approach and it comes out a little weird when you read it with a screen reader: "Level 1: HomeHome". A possible improvement here might be to only have the levels in that hidden span.

Comment: @VolkerE. ended up back here a year+ later, i'd recommend removing the h6 tag and using something else. Since breadcrumbs are at the top of the page, using an h6 there means the usage of headers are no longer compliant. Apparently the way this works in the top to bottom source ordering, header tags are not supposed to be duplicated and should always be descending. h1 h2 h3 h2 h3 invalid h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like below

```
<nav role="navigation"  aria-label="breadcrumbs">
    <p id="breadcrumblabel">You are here:</p>
    <ol id="breadcrumb" aria-labelledby="breadcrumblabel">
        <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html" title="Menu1">Menu1</a></li>
        <li><a href="shoes.html" title="Menu2">Menu2</a></li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: You do not need to apply a role attribute to `<nav>`, since it is already semantically appropriate.

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy, while in an ideal world the role is not needed because it is implied, some browsers don't treat the nav element correctly, so the aria role should be used for clarity.

Comment: This is a great solution. But I think the `You are here:` part should be an `<h2>` instead, so that the heading is added to the document outline.