# Should I use the ARIA directory role for a breadcrumbs list?

Tags: html, css, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to add accessibility to a **breadcrumbs** component, which is based on a `<ul>` element. I have been researching ARIA roles and I stumbled upon the [directory role](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#directory), which seems like a good fit. However, I cannot figure out if it really is a good fit or not for my breadcrumbs component and if my component implements whatever is required based on the role's description. A demo of my breadcrumbs list styling and structure is provided below:

```css
ul.breadcrumbs {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 8px;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
ul.breadcrumbs li {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-basis: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-right: 18px;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:before,
ul.breadcrumbs li:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0 solid #e0e0e0;
  border-width: 16px 8px;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:before {
  left: -16px;
  border-left-color: transparent;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:after {
  left: 100%;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-left-color: #e0e0e0;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:first-child:before {
  border: 0;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
ul.breadcrumbs li:last-child:after {
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcrumbs">
  <li><a href="#">Root</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Folder</a>
  </li>
  <li>File</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `breacrumbs` microformat uses the role `navigation`, which seems more appropriate :
http://microformats.org/wiki/breadcrumbs-formats

Read also, the following question:  [Proper ARIA handling of breadcrumb navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326699/proper-aria-handling-of-breadcrumb-navigation)

Comment: I believe `navigation` is a better fit than `directory`, but I did not really pay too much attention to it due to the fact I have `nav` elements in my pages which have the same role. Apparently, I can use labeling to deal with this problem, so I guess `navigation` is the better option after all!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No.** You should use the `navigation` role instead.

## Long answer

If you use the `<nav>` HTML5 element, the `navigation` role is automatically inferred.

```html
<nav></nav>

<!-- is equivalent to -->
<div role="navigation"></div>
```

A [fully accessible breadcrumb component](https://www.aditus.io/patterns/breadcrumbs/) can be implemented as follows:

[image: breadcrumbs screenshot]

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumbs">
  <ol>
    <li>
      <a href="/">
        Home
      </a>
      <span aria-hidden="true">→<span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/parent">
        Parent
      </a>
      <span aria-hidden="true">→<span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a
        href="/parent/current"
        aria-current="location"
      >
        Current
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Some notes:

- Use `<nav>` to automatically use the `navigation` landmark (your question).
- Use `aria-label` to provide a meaningful name to the `<nav>` (most likely, you have more `<nav>` elements on the page and you should label each one accordingly)
- Use `<ol>` to make the set of links structured as a hierarchy. This also helps screen reader users understand how "nested" your page is as it will be announce as **"breadcrumbs, navigation (next) list, 3 items"**
- Use `aria-current="location"` or `aria-current="page"` on the last page of the list to  mark it as the current page.
- (optional) if the breadcrumbs separator is implemented in HTML, make sure to hide it from screen reader users with `aria-hidden="true"`.